# send jQuery object (exif coordinates) to my table in MySql through php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

How can I send my converted exif coordinates (in decimals) to my db  using php and mysql? I'm using one file for this (addnew.php)

I'm sending information through a form in php like:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){

$username = $_POST['userName'];
$watervisibility = $_POST ['waterVisibility'];
$divinglocation = $_POST['divingLocation'];

$imgFile = $_FILES['user_art']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_art']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['user_art']['size'];
```

I also use libraries to convert exif to decimals ( on change ) to avoid clicking submit. This is all still in the same php file (addnew.php) (this is where i'm having a problem)

```
var lat;
var latref;
var long;
var longref;

var dec;
var myLatLng;

document.getElementById("input-group").onchange = function(e) {


EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {
    //console.log(EXIF.pretty(this));

    long = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude');
    longref = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitudeRef');

    lat = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitude');
    latref = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitudeRef');


    dec = dms2dec(long, longref, lat, latref);

    console.log("Decimal 1: " + dec[0] + " Decimal 2: " + dec[1]);

    console.log("Longref: " + longref);
    console.log("Latref: " + latref);

    console.log("Long Length: "  + long.length);

    console.log("Longtitude: " + long);
    console.log("Latitude: " + lat);

    myLatLng = {lat: dec[1], lng: dec[0]}

    myLat = {lat: dec[1]}
    myLng = {lng: dec[0]}

    console.log(myLat);
    console.log(myLng);


 });
 }
```

Now I got the decimals and basically just want to send

```
myLat = {lat: dec[1]}
myLng = {lng: dec[0]}
```

to my db through php at the same time i'm submitting everything else. 
I've tried Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP but I can't seem to get the hang of it

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To send javascript obj to php using json and ajax:

js:

```
var dataPost = {
   "var": "foo"
};
var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataPost);

$.ajax({
   url: 'server.php',
   data: {myData: dataString},
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

to use that object in php:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["myData"]);    
echo $obj->var;
```

Comment: I can't get it to work in that order from the same file. I have to send it to another php file and i need to submit from the same file (addnew.php)

Comment: Just replace server.php with addnew.php and use if(isset($_POST['myData'])). This is basic @Kejsaren, please take a tutorial.